# Material UI table extra padding

Tags: css, reactjs, html-table, material-ui

I am trying to adjust the padding of Material-UI Table. My issue is that the table I have made is having some extra padding on its top which cannot be removed (the yellow region in the below picture).
[image]
I have noticed that by removing "overflow-x" property this padding disappears but of course by this way I'm losing the scrolling feature.
I have also tried to play around with the rest of my app elements to check if any property applies but this is not the case here.

Comment: can you share your code pls?

Comment: It's pretty much the same as the documentation page (https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#fixed-header)

No any extra CSS is added

Comment: Something must be different or it would look like the demo. Do you add your own theme?

Comment: Figured it out! some CSS of another component mixed the things up. Thank you for your time!